# Lync Server 2013 Install-CSDatabase Failure

Tags: lync

I have been trying to get a Lync server setup in my test enviroment and I keep running into errors. Most of them I can resolve fairly quickly, but last one has me stumped. I get the error when Lync tries to Execute PowerShell command Install-CSDatabase, looking at the log file it tells me that it timed out. I am not sure why it would time out, it is being installed on the same server as the SQL instance.

Server is a Windows Server 2012 R2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running this on a VM in a test host, which has some pretty low I/O specs. I moved the VM to a host with higher I/O specs and the installation completed. Apparently, it was taking too long to complete the transaction and it timed out.